# IE image issue when changing heights using 'background-size: cover'

Tags: jquery, css

In IE 9+, using `background-size: cover` is fine except when using it with jQuery to expand the height of an element. The background is stretching like its suppose to but it leaves some background image artifacts from the previous height.

It only happens when there is a scroll bar present. Re-sizing the window can fix it if the user takes the time to do that.

You can see the issue here:
https://jsfiddle.net/g2afLhv5/4/

Screenshots here:
http://imgur.com/a/jhoxo

Is there any way around this using JS or CSS?

Comment: IE 8 ? I won't bother about a 6 year old browser which is out of support ...

Comment: It's on IE  8, 9, 10, Edge; hence the 8+

Comment: So, as it might also occur on Navigator 4.5, you're going to ask for NS 4.5+ ??

Comment: Works totally fine w/o any artifacts on IE11/Win7

Comment: IE8 does not support COVER. Ass Axel said, IE8 is old browser.
Check this stats >> http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: Not really, I'm fine with just 10 and Edge. I'm pointing out that it happens on older versions as well. Some screenshots of the issue: Using IE Edge http://imgur.com/a/jhoxo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap the content with a `<div class="body-wrapper">`and apply the background image to this wrapper.

```js
$('.t1').click(function() {
  $('.box').css('height','900px');
});
$('.t2').click(function() {
  $('.box').css('height','1900px');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.body-wrapper {
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/b7RXF5u.gif') center 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.box {
  margin: 50px 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  min-height: 900px;
  clear: both;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.tabs {
  float: right;
}
.tabs div {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body-wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="t1">Tab1</div>
    <div class="t2">Tab2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's an unsightly fix for IE but it does fix the problem. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Hi just add the background-attachment property fixed to the body

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Here is a working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/okouobeu/

Comment: While this does not allow the background to scale with the various heights, it is a nice simple workaround to the problem and does have its uses, +1. Thank you, sir.